# EE3 'Error: The URL contains too many segments'

Tags: error, url

I am getting an 'Error: The URL contains too many segments' from the following code:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="performances" show_group="3" dynamic="no" style="linear"}
<li><a href="performances/category/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Not sure what to do. Every time I click on the link it ‘appends’ another segment until I get the error message.

Answer (score 3):

As I said on Slack: put a slash before the URL so it's not relative to the current page like so `/performances/category/{category_url_title}`

Comment: If that answered your question, please mark Jelle's answer as "accepted."